# C# Google Drive API Empty Files List

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to get a list of names of files from Google Drive but I get an empty list each time

- I created a project on [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- I enabled [Google Drive API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com)
- I created a user in [OAuth consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)
- I created credentials [OAuth 2.0 Client IDs](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and downloaded it as json

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string ApplicationName = "TestGoogleDriveAPI";

        private static UserCredential GetCredentials()
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "drive-dot-net-quickstart.json");
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, false)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                return credential;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential = GetCredentials();

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            //listRequest.Q = "name contains 'EMR_backup_' and createdTime > '2020-12-01T12:00:00' and modifiedTime > '2021-07-01T12:00:00'";
            //listRequest.Q = "parents in '10ybGwqq7J_GbA7JvG6C8aiTFNRsdzdk7'";
            //listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            //listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            //FileList result = listRequest.Execute();

            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the actual text to your question.

Comment: YOu might want to start by cleaning up your code why are you calling listRequest.Execute() twice?  https://youtu.be/pHOweM1Gl6c

Comment: I cleaned it and it works properly now. Thanks